Aligning data in r with different time points

So got a set of data as in the example above. Need to plot in R the dependent variable as a function of log number. My issue is that the point at which the intensity changes from 100 to 1000 needs to align on the graph for all the reps when all data is plotted together.
This is also an issue when averaging the reps out.
My gut feeling is that the point at which intensity increases from 100 to 1000 needs to be the point 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated
Whatever I have tried didnt work out
